# Unable to run page from Jdevelper

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

When I try to run a page from inside Jdeveloper, I am getting below error.
Error: jar:file:/C:/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar!/ does not exist.

How to solve this problem?